# I just installed Node.js and then React.js, need some spoonfeeding on how to display a single Semantic UI component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, semantic-ui

I'm actually getting a little overwhelmed here.. I've googled a LOT but I haven't figured out how to see a React component on my page.. I'm super new to web development although I know basics of HTML, CSS and JavaScript

Here are all the steps I've followed right from installing Node, they are pretty standard steps..

1. Install Node from `.pkg`
2. Add path to `.bash_profile`
3. Go to a parent directory and then do `sudo npm install create-react-app -g`, although I don't think going to any particular directory matters since `-g` means it will be installed globally.
4. Stay inside a parent directory and then do `create-react-app project_name`
5. `npm start`: Which showed me a default page with a nice React logo
6. In the same folder `project_name` which was created from the `create-react-app` step, I ran `npm install -g gulp`
7. I then ran `npm install semantic-ui --save` as listed on Semantic UI website
8. `npm audit fix` to fix some issue it said are critical (running this didn't change anything)
9. In `project_name` folder, I ran `cd semantic`
10. And then folder `semantic`, I did `gulp build`

This is how I assume I am supposed to install Semantic UI.

To now help you understand how my project is structured, it looks like this:

[image: <code>project_name</code> structure]

All of these files are the standard default files that are created when you do `create-react-app..` and follow the steps I've done

My `App.js` which even you can recreate looks like this (this file I'm assuming is what renders whatever is inside `return()` to the `root` div present in `index.html` located in the directory `public` which you can see in my image..

In the same `index.html` in the `public` folder, I also add this portion in the `<head>` section

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic/dist/semantic.min.css">
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

which I'm assuming is what brings in all the Semantic UI components..

Let's say I want to see this [Multiple Selection component of Semantic UI](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#types-multiple-selection)

which is defined by this code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const options = [
  { key: 'angular', text: 'Angular', value: 'angular' },
  { key: 'css', text: 'CSS', value: 'css' },
  { key: 'design', text: 'Graphic Design', value: 'design' },
  { key: 'ember', text: 'Ember', value: 'ember' },
  { key: 'html', text: 'HTML', value: 'html' },
  { key: 'ia', text: 'Information Architecture', value: 'ia' },
  { key: 'javascript', text: 'Javascript', value: 'javascript' },
  { key: 'mech', text: 'Mechanical Engineering', value: 'mech' },
  { key: 'meteor', text: 'Meteor', value: 'meteor' },
  { key: 'node', text: 'NodeJS', value: 'node' },
  { key: 'plumbing', text: 'Plumbing', value: 'plumbing' },
  { key: 'python', text: 'Python', value: 'python' },
  { key: 'rails', text: 'Rails', value: 'rails' },
  { key: 'react', text: 'React', value: 'react' },
  { key: 'repair', text: 'Kitchen Repair', value: 'repair' },
  { key: 'ruby', text: 'Ruby', value: 'ruby' },
  { key: 'ui', text: 'UI Design', value: 'ui' },
  { key: 'ux', text: 'User Experience', value: 'ux' },
]

const DropdownExampleMultipleSelection = () => (
  <Dropdown placeholder='Skills' fluid multiple selection options={options} />
)

export default DropdownExampleMultipleSelection
```

In which specific file do I add this code above and have the UI rendered/returned when I do `npm start`?

You can recreate my file structure from a folder if you follow the steps I've listed above..

Comment: Need to install `semantic-ui-react` .... http://react.semantic-ui.com/usage. And no need for jQuery and no need for gulp in `create-react-app`

Comment: @charlietfl Ohhh.. Okay.. So by default Semantic UI has two ways to be used.. The jQuery way and the React way. And I have installed the default one which is the jQuery implementation, forgive me for sounding like a potato.. I'm new to JavaScript.. I currently have the jQuery installed version of Semantic UI.. Do I just LET IT STAY THERE and then do `yarn add semantic-ui-react` Where do I now copy paste the React based code of Semantic UI

Comment: Can use `npm` instead of `yarn` if that's what you are working with. Also get rid of jQuery. You should not need it in a `create-react-app`

Comment: @charlietfl If you can post your instructions as an answer, I can upvote it and Accept it.. What do I do after I go into the project folder and do `yarn add semantic-ui-react`? Thanks for your help!

Comment: There are full examples of all components as well as source code for each example in the link above. The source code also shows the imports

Comment: @charlietfl I figured it out sir. Thank you so much. I literally replaced everything in the default App.js and it worked. Can you post some answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score -1):

Try in App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DropdownExampleMultipleSelection from '/path/yourFile';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
           <DropdownExampleMultipleSelection></DropdownExampleMultipleSelection> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```